# Error in gseGO(geneList = foldchanges, OrgDb = org.Dm.eg.db, ont = "All",

Tags: r

I'm trying to do gene ontology.Using R
(GO) and I have the following error, could you help me with the code or if possible with a tutorial to be able to do this analysis

gseaGO1 <- gseGO(geneList = foldchanges,

- ```
               OrgDb = org.Dm.eg.db,
  ```
- ```
               ont = 'All',
  ```
- ```
               nPerm = 1000,
  ```
- ```
               minGSSize = 10,
  ```
- ```
               pvalueCutoff = 0.05,
  ```
- ```
               verbose = FALSE)
  ```

Error in gseGO(geneList = foldchanges, OrgDb = org.Dm.eg.db, ont = "All",  :
could not find function "gseGO"

I am following the Gene Set Enrichment Analysis with ClusterProfiler tutorial from https://learn.gencore.bio.nyu.edu/rna-seq-analysis/gene-set-enrichment-analysis/

Comment: You need to install or load the clusterProfiler package : `BiocManager::install("clusterProfiler")` and `library(clusterProfiler)`